# Segmentation Fault in my RSA algorithm program

Tags: segmentation-fault, rsa

pls check the following code ..its the RSA algorithm which i'm trying to implement with p and q declared as 17 and 11...the program gives segmentation fault(core dumped) as error after prompting the user to input the plain text M...what does this mean and why is it giving this error??...any help would be appreciated.. :)

```
#include<iostream>     


#include<math.h>

using namespace std;

class RSA         
{    
public:    
long M,phi,d,e,n,c;        
int p,q;         
RSA();            
void calculate();            
long relprime();        
long gcd(long,long);          
void encrypt();         
void decrypt();         
};


RSA::RSA()        
{           
cout<<"enter the plain text M";         
cin>>M;         
p=17;      
q=11;    
}    

void RSA::calculate()        
{           

n=p*q;             
phi=(q-1)*(p-1);             
e=(long)relprime();              

cout<<e;  


d=0;           

while(d==0)            
{              
for(int k=1;;k++)                 
{                 
if((phi*k+1)%e==0)              
d=(phi*k+1)/e;             
}            
}       



cout<<d; 


}          



long RSA::relprime()              
{                  

for(int i=2;i<phi;i++)      


{               
if(gcd(i,phi)==1)           
return (long)i;              
}        
}             

long RSA::gcd(long a,long b)              
{              

if(a<b)        


{                   
if(a%b==0)                    
return a;              
else gcd(b-a,a);            
}             
else gcd(b,a);              
}              


void RSA::encrypt()              
{            
c=(long)pow(M,e);             
c=c%n;                

cout<<"encrypted c="<<c;  


}          

void RSA::decrypt()            
{             
M=(long)pow(c,d);          
M=M%n;            

cout<<"plain text="<<M;  


}           

int main()          
{            
RSA r;            
r.calculate();             
r.encrypt();        
r.decrypt();             
return 0;         
}
```

Comment: "Seg fault" means you are accessing memory that you don't own.  You should run your program in a debugger to find which line causes the issue, and then go from there.

Comment: found that  cin>>M in the constructor causes the issue...so declared M as some value but still the same seg-fault error..i dont think i am accessing any memory that i dont own..

Answer (score 1):

Since there does not appear to be any pointer handling going on, the next best idea might be a stack overflow. I notice that your gcd function is implemented recursively, and will never abort the recursion if it is ever called with equal parameters (a==b). Perhaps the line `if(a<b)` should be `if(a>=b)` instead?

Edit: That does not seem right either... you might want to check that method as a whole :)